# How I can pass a value in format.html with redirect_to in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried to pass uuid and msg in the `format.html { redirect_to @sample, notice: { uuid: @sample.uuid, msg: @sample.msg }` to display in the view but I think it's not the proper way of passing a value.

And when I want to access in the view

`<%= flash[:notice][:code] %>`
`<%= flash[:notice][:id] %>`

doesn't display the flash..

Comment: `format.html { redirect_to @sample, uuid: @sample.uuid }` and in view `<%= flash[:uuid] %>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to access those values via flash, try the following:

```
format.html { redirect_to @sample, flash: { uuid: @sample.uuid, msg: @sample.msg } }
```

You can then access them via `<%= flash[:uuid] %>` or `<%= flash[:msg] %>`

Hope it helps!